# RestClient getResponse() work on android 2.3 but not work on 4.0.4

Tags: android, web-services, rest-client, getresponse

I have this code for get data from web

```
String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/services/login.php";
                RestClient client = new RestClient(LOGIN_URL );
                client.AddParam("email", tbEmail.getText().toString());
                client.AddParam("pwd", Password);
                client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
                String response = client.getResponse();

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
```

And in emulator with Android 2.3 work fine and in response are my data, but when I run this same code on my phone with Android 4.0.4 (CyanogenMod9), in response are null.
Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Have you got any error ? Please check in logcat and post here .
Have you got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much.... I reinstall my phone and I forget set DroidWall. You save me :D Thanks...